# Slow BlazeGraph SPARQL Queries with UNION and FILTER

Tags: sparql, blazegraph, wikidata-query-service

I'm doing SPARQL queries on [Blazegraph](https://github.com/blazegraph/database) RDF Graph database against the [Wikidata query service](https://query.wikidata.org/). These queries involve several UNION and typically a FILTER like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?music_track ?music_trackLabel ?artist ?artistLabel ?album ?albumLabel ?publication_date WHERE {
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }

      { ?music_track wdt:P31 wd:Q134556. }
      UNION
      { ?music_track wdt:P31 wd:Q7366. }
      UNION
      { ?music_track wdt:P31 wd:Q2188189. }
      UNION
      { ?music_track wdt:P31 wd:Q207628. }
      UNION
      { ?music_track wdt:P31 wd:Q7302866. }
      UNION
      { ?music_track wdt:P31 wd:Q9748. }
      UNION
      { ?music_track wdt:P2207 ?_spotifyTrackID_. }

      ?music_track rdfs:label ?music_trackLabel.

      ?music_track wdt:P175 ?artist. 
      ?artist rdfs:label ?artistLabel.

      OPTIONAL { ?music_track wdt:P361 ?album.}
      OPTIONAL { ?music_track wdt:P577 ?publication_date. }

      FILTER regex(?music_trackLabel, "^Castle on the Hill$", "i")
      FILTER (regex(?artistLabel, "ed sheeran", "i"))
    }
    LIMIT 10
```

or like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?artist ?artistLabel ?birth_nameLabel  ?date ?website ?instagramID ?facebookID ?twitterID ?musicBrainzArtistID WHERE {
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }

    { ?artist wdt:P31 wd:Q215380. }
    UNION
    { ?artist wdt:P31 wd:Q2088357. }
    UNION
    { ?artist wdt:P31 wd:Q5741069. }
    UNION
    { ?artist wdt:P31 wd:Q641066. }
     UNION
    { ?artist wdt:P1902 ?_spotifyArtistID_. }
    UNION
    { ?artist wdt:P2850 ?_itunesArtistID_. }
    UNION
    { ?artist wdt:P434 ?musicBrainzArtistID. } 

      FILTER(REGEX(?artistLabel, "^Fall Out Boy$", "i"))
      ?artist rdfs:label ?artistLabel.

      OPTIONAL { ?artist wdt:P571 ?date. }
      OPTIONAL { ?artist wdt:P1477 ?birth_nameLabel. }
      OPTIONAL { ?artist wdt:P856 ?website. }
      OPTIONAL { ?artist wdt:P2003 ?instagramID. }
      OPTIONAL { ?artist wdt:P2013 ?facebookID. }
      OPTIONAL { ?artist wdt:P2002 ?twitterID. }


  }
  LIMIT 10
```

Those queries are very slow (ranging from few of seconds to more than ten seconds) and I would like to optimize those queries.

Using the Blazegraph dashboard I did a query EXPLAIN, but I didn't get an understanding of how and what to optimize.

Comment: 1) It's very slow because of your REGEX for sure. and unfortunately, there is no fulltext index support for Wikidata 2) use `VALUES` instead of multiple `UNION` as long as you have the same predicate 3) there is a [mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/bigdata/mailman/bigdata-developers/) 4) it was bought by Amazon, I don't think it will be maintained that long in the future

Comment: @AKSW thank you this makes sense, I will have a look and try to refactor `UNION` with `VALUES`.

Comment: @AKSW not clear to me how to use `VALUES` instead of `UNION`. Thank you!

Comment: Only usefull here for triple patterns have something in common, e.g. `VALUES ?artistType {wd:Q215380 wd:Q2088357wd:Q5741069 wd:Q641066} ?artist wdt:P31 ?artistType .` - but I don't think this will improve the performance. The bottleneck is the REGEX + maybe also the bunch of left-joins (OPTIONAL)